# Update query is not updating the corresponding row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have encountered a strange problem in Codeigniter. I am running a query that updates a row:

```
function set_counter($key, $value){
    echo "$key : $value => ";
    $this->db->query("UPDATE counter SET counter.`value` = ? WHERE counter.`key` = ?", array($value, $key));
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Benchmark shows that this function gets called and query does run:

```
UPDATE counter SET counter.`value` = 1 WHERE counter.`key` = 'left_banner_start_id'
```

The function returns '1' which means 1 row gets updated.

But in actual the row doesn't get updated in database, `value` column is always '0'

Any solution what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:**

The problem gets even weirder, when I exit() my function, the row actually gets updated, otherwise it doesn't:

```
function set_counter($key, $value){
    echo "$key : $value - ";
    $this->db->query("UPDATE counter SET counter.`value` = ? WHERE counter.`key` = ?", array($value, $key));
    //print_r($this->db->affected_rows());
    exit();
}
```

**Edit:**

Alright, it works if I exit() the execution here in system/core/Output.php:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Does the controller contain a function named _output()?
    // If so send the output there.  Otherwise, echo it.
    if (method_exists($CI, '_output'))
    {
        $CI->_output($output);
    }
    else
    {
        exit();
        echo $output;  // Send it to the browser!
    }
```

but doesn't work if I exit() it after echoing $output:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Does the controller contain a function named _output()?
    // If so send the output there.  Otherwise, echo it.
    if (method_exists($CI, '_output'))
    {
        $CI->_output($output);
    }
    else
    {
        echo $output;  // Send it to the browser!
        exit();
    }
```

**Edit:**

In my view there is this line that was preventing it:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url().$recent_ad['photo_thumb']; ?>" width="28" height="27" />
```

and this one in another view:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url().$featured_agent['photo_medium']; ?>" width="84" height="84" />
```

Here photo_thumb and photo_medium are column's in another table in database, they had null values. I filled the columns and now it's working fine.

But why? What is the reason?

Comment: Is it print the correct values in function?

Comment: Yes. Everything is fine. Even codeigniter shows that query runs without an error and shows that 1 row has updated in db. But in actual nothing gets updated.

Comment: i think according to echo "$key : $value => "; not printing the value

Comment: I was just debugging using that statement. It is printing the values as I have already told in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to switch your code for active record syntax?

```
function set_counter($key, $value){
    $this->db->where('key', $key)->update('counter', array('value' => $value));
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Comment: Then, maybe you could show us where this method is called from. The thing is that you're facing a problem which won't be anything on CI engine, since it's a common update query. Most likely a invalid value. Actually you said that photo_thumb, and photo_medium are data retrieved by other tables. Is there any possibility that you are doing a INNER JOIN, associating these values and getting the counter.key value by this same query? Because then, there would be no key if you're doing a INNER with something null.

Comment: That's the thing which is bugging me so much. photo_thumb and photo_medium are totally unrelated columns. The query didn't have to do anything with these columns or even the table.
And no, $key and $value are valid fields (and no inner join is used), I told that codeigniter does show that the query has run successfully (but data doesn't get updated)
This was got by the benchmark: `UPDATE counter SET counter.value = 1 WHERE counter.key = 'left_banner_start_id'` so there is no error in the query.